# Implementing the onClickListener of a textView that is used inside an ArrayAdapter for ListView(Fragment)

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onclick

I was using a listActivity but I decided to use a navigation bar so I switched to using fragments. I am trying to implement the onClick methods for myTextViews but I cant make it work. I also cannot call constructor with super inside setOnItemClickListener. So I want to implement quickQuiz and longQuiz methods inside my fragment. How can I do it? Here is the related piece of my code.

```
public class ListFriendFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayAdapter myAdapter;
    private ListView myListView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vx=getView();
        myListView =(ListView)vx.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {
            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listfriends, container, false);


    }
```

I set up my adapter with this.

```
 myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.fragment_listfriendsmenu, R.id.mylistText, listValues);
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

When I try to create a new method called quickQuiz (as expected) it warns me saying that android.view.View is never used

Here is fragment_listfriends.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Main2Activity"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Friends"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is listfriends_menu.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mylistText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#3700ff" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quizchallenge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="QuickQuiz"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#26ff00"
                android:onClick="quickQuiz"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/longQuiz"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LongQuiz"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="longQuiz"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ff0400" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the fragment class for the sole purpose of inflating the fragment. Then putting the method in your main activity, and not inside your fragment. Better if your `inflater` is also inside you main activity. Here a sample.

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfrag, container, false);
    }
}
```

You should put it on your MainActivity class.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_myfrag"
    android:name="com.example.user.frag.MainActivity$MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

and put this in your activity_main layout.

And instead of onClickListener, you could also use `android:onClick="myfunction"`
Yes, I know that we have different styles of programming, but I wish this could help you on your problem. Have a good day.

P.S.
    My fragment doesn't have a java file of it's own. The classes are all on my MainActivty.java. And I don't use `onClickListener`. What I have is `android:onClick` on my layout file. What my `android:onClick="myfunction"` calls is `myfunction(View view){function here}` which does the same as an `onClickListener`.

Comment: I understood your approach but if I try to change into this fragment with FragmentManager in my NavigationBarActivity() would it work like this? I am  new to Fragments

Comment: Do you use `FragmentManager` to make the fragments visible and invisible? If that's the case, you could just put the fragment into a linearlayout/relativelayout and play with their `android:visibility=""`. You can use either `VISIBLE` or `GONE` depending on what you want. It's easier than fragmentmanager, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In this situations my suggest is create a custom adapter to have more flexibility and make onClicks methods.
Like this:

Create a interface:
**MyOnViewClickListener.java**

```
public interface MyOnViewClickListener {
    public void myOnViewClickListener(View v, int position);
}
```

Create your custom adapter class:
**MyCustomAdapter.java**

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{ //Here its a example with Strings, but feel free to pass the object you want

    private Context context;
    private MyOnViewClickListener itemListener;
    private List<String> items;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> items, MyOnViewClickListener itemListener) {

            this.itemListener = itemListener;
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
    }


    public static class CustomHolder
    {
            String quickQuizText;
            String longQuizText;

            TextView quickQuiz;
            TextView longQuiz;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

            CustomHolder holder = new CustomHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfriends_menu, parent, false); //Inflate with your row's layout

            hoolder.quickQuiz = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quizchallenge);
            hoolder.longQuiz = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.longQuiz);

        quickQuiz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        itemListener.myOnViewClickListener(v,position);
                    }
            });

            row.setTag(holder);
            setupItem(holder);
            return row;
    }

    private void setupItem(CustomHolder h)
    {
            h.quickQuiz.setText(h.quickQuizText);
            h.longQuiz.setText(h.longQuizText);
    }
}
```

Finally, in your fragment class, **implement the new interface**:

```
public class ListFriendFragment extends Fragment implements MyOnViewClickListener  {
.
.
.
int listPosition;
@Override
public void myOnViewClickListener(View v, int position){
    listPosition = position;
    //call your method
    quickQuiz();
}
```

Set up the adapter

```
adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), listValues, MyFragment.this);
```

This way, it's a bit more complicate but allows you do everything you want with your listview.

Comment: How can I find the position of element that is selected with this way?

Comment: In the **getView()** method, there is an argument that indicates the item's position in the list. I edited the code for the interface also receive the position.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but there are a few problems. First there is a typo in holder(hoolder). Second when I am trying to setOnClickListener I think I should do it with holder.quickQuiz not only quickQuiz. getLayoutInflater doesnt work for adapter so I used LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);   And for the constructor android studio gives me an error stating that no default constructor is available in widget.arrayadapter so I think I should call super with some parameters but I couldnt find what they are

Comment: I gave super(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1); to the constructor. Then in my fragment class I set adapter with  myAdapter = new ListFragmentAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), listValues, ListFriendFragment.this);
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);    The problem is that I cannot see any of elements in myListView in the screen and I am %100 sure it has an element. The layout only displays the textview I write in fragment_listfriends.xml